# The hidden __result local variable in armcc DWARF debug information

Tags: arm, dwarf, armcc

I'm writing tools for debugging Cortex-M and I have discovered an artefact when reviewing the DWARF `.debug_info` section which the armcc outputs for some C source. (The exact compiler is ARM Compiler 5.05.)

For example when the C source contains a simple function such as:

```
int function(int a)
{
    int x;
    int y;
```

I have discovered that the `.debug_info` describes the x and y local variables as expected, and additionally a "hidden variable" called `__result` as follows:

```
<2><218>: Abbrev Number: 94 (DW_TAG_variable)
  <219>   DW_AT_name        : __result
  <222>   DW_AT_type        : DW_FORM_ref2 <0x188>
  <225>   DW_AT_location    : 1 byte block: 50  (DW_OP_reg0 (r0))
  <227>   DW_AT_start_scope : 64
  <228>   DW_AT_artificial  : 1
```

The clue of the "hidden" nature of this "variable", being the presence of the `DW_AT_artificial` flag.

I've have read the DWARF documentation regarding the `DW_AT_artificial` flag, which confirmed by suspicions. I've also deduced by experimentation that this feature relates to return value which this function, since this "variable" does not appear in the DWARF for a `void` typed function.

What I cannot find is any confirmation of this entity's use as intended by the designers of the `armcc` toolchain. Can anybody elaborate on the meaning and usage of my discovery?